# Unable to send cookie with HTTPOnly flag in request header in safari

Tags: java, security, cookies, browser, safari

I created cookies with **HTTPOnly** flag in **Safari** browser using java 
See Response header below.

```html
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer:http://anil.mlbextrabases.com/SafariIssue/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
userName:servlet
userPass:servlet
flagRequired:true
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:331
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Wed, 08 Aug 2018 09:23:45 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:userInfo="username: servletpassword: servlet"; Version=1; Comment="creating cookie"; Domain=anil.mlbextrabases.com; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Thu, 08-Aug-2019 09:23:45 GMT; Path=";Path=/;HttpOnly;", JSESSIONID=076942707A8D62AD1296102A1593F664; Path=/SafariIssue; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=7776000; includeSubdomains
```

But cookies are not passed in subsequent requests in **safari** browser. While passing in other browsers like **Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge**
When i removed **HTTPOnly** flag cookies are passing good in Safari browser as well.

I did a lot of R&D over developer communities. But it not helped.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

I'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: have the same, any luck, anyone?

Comment: More info - [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301884/safari-not-setting-cors-cookies-using-js-fetch-api)