# Safari not include COOKIE to second CORS request

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, cross-domain

I have frontend on `https://somedomain.dev` (angular) and api on `https://api.somedomain.dev` (so I have same domain but different subdomain - this is important because for different whole domains Safari will [block](https://elixirforum.com/t/set-cookie-header-works-on-google-chrome-and-ff-but-no-safari/20867) all [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53157622/860099)). I send 3 requests to API in following order

- `POST /api/user/login` - in response server set **HttpOnly** COOKIE (with authorisation token: JWT
- `GET /api/user/profile` - to get user profile (browser should add COOKIE to request)
- `GET /api/buildings` - to get buildings (browser should add COOKIE to request)

**Problem**: Safari add cookie only for `GET profile` and NOT add cookie to `GET buildings` (Chrome, Firefox and Edge add COOKIE to each GET request)

All requests details (headers etc.):

- Chrome v.81.0 : [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SpGy.png), [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7qhS.png) and [building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7Ax.png)
- Safari v. 13.1 : [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vxlo.png), [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NwSe.png) and [building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVcPz.png)
- angular: each get request is send with `withCredential: true` flag (and of course this works in Chrome)

**Question**: Why Safari not add cookie to `buildings` request and what to do to force Safari (using javascript or server code) to add cookie to all requests (after login) ?

Comment: And you are using `withCredentials` on both requests?

Comment: @David - yes - on all requests (I use interceptor do do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - after loooong analysing requests finally I found the problem - in `login` response the server set in `Set-Cookie` header the cookie life time by

```
Max-Age: 43200;
```

this works on Chrome, Firefox and Edge - but NOT on Safari (probably Safari treat this as 1s cookie life-time and this is why it add cookie only for first GET request) - so I change it to

```
max-age=43200;
```

and now works everywhere :)